# adding different child lists for each parent in ExpandableListView for Android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an Expandable List view with the parent list showing Store names.
The child element should be the first line of the address, one on each. 
Currently the code sets the parent element correctly however every parent element contains all of the child elements rather than just the one relating to it.

Any ideas?

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        //System.out.println(debugName.get(i));

    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();


for (int i = 0; i < debugName.size(); i++) {

    storeName = debugName.get(i);
    listDataHeader.add(storeName);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
```

//Store name prints properly so: Store 1, Store 2, Store 3 etc. one for each parent element.

```
}

    for (int i = 0; i < address1.size(); i++) {
        storeAddress = address1.get(i);

        System.out.println(storeAddress);
```

//store address prints address for store 1, 2, 3 under each parent

```
        top250.add(storeAddress);


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), top250);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the source code, it looks to me like you're adding **all store addresses** into `top250`.

`listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), top250)` is therefore assigning all the store addresses under each header every time.

Try changing that line to `listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), top250.get(i))` and see if it's any closer to what you wanted.

Of course, this might not be what you expect yet, because this assumes that each header has exactly one address and that the `listDataHeader` items are matched with each `top250` item but you can start from there.